# Insert multiple values and Insert value in parallel

Tags: sql

I have a question about SQL in parallel queries. For example, suppose that I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO tblExample (num) VALUES (1), (2)
```

And this query:

```
INSERT INTO tblExample (num) VALUES (3)
```

The final table should looked like this:

```
num
---
1
2
3
```

But I wonder if there is an option that those two queries will run in parallel and the final table will be looked like this:

```
num
---
1
3
2
```

Someone know the answer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In SQL, a table doesn't have any specific ordering or sequence of data. If you need a specific order, you have to define it by using `ORDER BY` - so it really doesn't matter whether you insert `1, 2, 3` or `1, 3, 2` into your table - your table just contains these three values, and you can select them in any order you need to - by specifying the appropriate `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 1):

How your table "looks" depends on how you asked for it (in the `SELECT` statement). Without an [`ORDER BY` clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by), the order of your table is undefined:

> ORDER BY is the only way to sort the rows in the result set. Without this clause, the relational database system may return the rows in any order. If an ordering is required, the ORDER BY must be provided in the SELECT statement sent by the application.

For example:

```
SELECT num FROM tblExample ORDER BY num ASC
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

```
SELECT num FROM tblExample ORDER BY num DESC
```

> 3
>
> 2
>
> 1

If you want to order your columns manually, you can add a new column and sort on it:

```
+-----+-------+
| num | order |
+-----+-------+
| 1   | 1     |
| 2   | 3     |
| 3   | 2     |
+-----+-------+

SELECT num FROM tblExample ORDER BY order ASC
```

> 1
>
> 3
>
> 2

Comment: No, the num is just an example. My question is if there is an option that those two queries will run in parallel and the final table (with simple SELECT command) will be looked like this: 1,2,3 . This is not what I want to, but I ask what can be happen if two queries run in parallel.

Comment: @OriSeri If you want to run two queries in parallel, just.. run them both at the same time. In most languages, it's easiest to use a different connection for each thread. If you're doing your stuff asyncronously, some of the databases provide APIs for that now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no order in sql. You can sort your queries by adding an `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT * FROM tblExample ORDER BY num
```

Or you could add a timestamp column to the table and order by that.